# splitting a string read from a file/istringstream

Tags: c++, split, formatting, istringstream

I'm currently taking an online C++ class and our current project requires us to read a file, take each student and put it into a vector.

My current problem is splitting the name read and setting it to the right variables.

The professor's pseudo code here:

```
inputFile.open(sFileName.c_str ());
while(inputFile.fail())
{
cout ERROR OPENING FILE
cout PLEASE REENTER THE PASSWORD OF THE FILE
getline(cin >> wd, sFileName);
inputFile.open(sFileName.c_str());
}

inputFile.clear();
inputFile.seek(0, ios::beg);

while(getline(inputFile, sTemp))
{
istringstream inputSStream(sTemp)
inputSStream >> sFirstName >> sMiddleName >> sLastName >> sID >> sClass;
if(sMiddleName != "|")
sFullName = sFirst name + " " + sMiddleName +" " + sLastName;
else
sFullName = sFirstName + " " + sLastName;
```

My current code here:

```
        ifstream myFile;
        string firstName, middleName, lastName, fullName, studentID, cID;
        string inFileName, stringTemp;
        cout << "Please enter the name of the file that you want to read in. \n";
        cin >> inFileName;

        myFile.open(inFileName);
        while (myFile.fail())
        {
            cout << "\n""";
            cout << "Error file, Please re-enter file. \n ";
            cin >> inFileName;
            myFile.open(inFileName);
        }
        myFile.clear();
        myFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        while (getline(myFile, stringTemp))
        {
            istringstream inputStream(stringTemp);
            inputStream >> firstName >> middleName >> lastName >> studentID >> cID;
            if (middleName != "|")
                fullName = firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;
            else
                fullName = firstName + " " + lastName; 


            //Checking what the input values are
            cout << "First name is " << firstName << endl;
            cout << "Middle name name is " << middleName << endl;
            cout << "Last name is " << lastName << endl;
            cout << "studentID is " << studentID << endl;
            cout << "CID is " << cID << endl;

            Student thisStudent(fullName, studentID, cID);
            studentList.push_back(thisStudent);

        }



        myFile.close();
```

The current problem is that the line isn't split correctly, first name gets the whole line and mid and last name, studentID and cID all remain empty.

Here is the current file that I'm reading in:

```
ERIC,ANTHONY,TURNER,1234573,CISC_198
GABRIEL,FEIJO,LOPES,1234574,CISC_199
GEOFFERY,BRYAN,RANSOM,1234575,CISC_200
HANNAH,MAE ,LONGRIE,1234576,CISC_201
HASSAN,ISMAIL,AHMED,1234577,CISC_202
HUNG,B,PHAM,1234578,CISC_203
HUSSEIN,FOUAD,ALJANABI,1234579,CISC_204
JING,XUN,CHEN,1234580,CISC_205
KAJALBEN,CHIMANLAL,MAKWANA,1234581,CISC_206
DANDREA,SHAMAICAH,BUSH,1234570,CISC_195
DANIELLE,MARIE,CORTEZ,1234571,CISC_196
ERDI,T,KIDANE,1234572,CISC_197
AARON,FABIAN,LINGAD,1234567,CISC_192
AARON,T,PATCHIN,1234568,CISC_193
ALI,FOUAD,ALJANABI,1234569,CISC_194
NATHAN,|,NANN,1234585,CISC_210
NEIL,ANDREAS,FRANKA,1234586,CISC_211
OBONE,|,ORIYAVONG,1234587,CISC_212
OLIVIA,JOANNE,MAILANDER,1234588,CISC_213
RALEIGH,|,COSGROVE,1234589,CISC_214
RYAN,PAREDES,PALMARES,1234590,CISC_215
MICHAEL,DUONG,NGUYEN,1234583,CISC_208
MIGLENA,|,CHEMELEKOVA,1234584,CISC_209
STEPHEN,MICHAEL,HOUSE,1234591,CISC_216
MARCUS,D,BUTLER,1234582,CISC_207
```

Here is the output that I do not understand how to fix.

```
First name is ERIC,ANTHONY,TURNER,1234573,CISC_198
Middle name name is
Last name is
studentID is
CID is
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read with `operator >>` you are splitting on whitespace.  Despite the name, `getline()` can split by other characters than newline:

```
getline(inputStream, firstName, ',');
getline(inputStream, middleName, ',');
// ...
```